# Errors trying to install Paramiko via pip

Tags: python, osx-lion, paramiko

I am trying to install paramiko via the terminal in OS so I can follow this tutorial:
http://www.macdrifter.com/2012/05/automated-ftp-from-dropbox-with-hazel/

I used the OKG from the python site to install the latest version (3.2.3) but I see 2.7 in the code.  I am still very n3wb when it comes to terminal, so not sure what some of these errors mean or what to do about them (Or how to decipher the logs accurately). Greatly appreciate any assistance (I stripped out a bunch of 'copying' lines, signified by the .............  This is everything from the initial command to the end.

```
sudo pip install paramiko

Downloading/unpacking paramiko
  Downloading paramiko-1.7.7.1.zip (1.1Mb): 1.1Mb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package paramiko

Downloading/unpacking pycrypto>=2.1 (from paramiko)
  Downloading pycrypto-2.5.tar.gz (426Kb): 426Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycrypto

Installing collected packages: paramiko, pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for paramiko

  Running setup.py install for pycrypto
    checking for gcc... no
    checking for cc... no
    checking for cl.exe... no
    configure: error: in `/Users/username/build/pycrypto':
    configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
    See `config.log' for more details

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/username/build/pycrypto/setup.py", line 452, in <module>
        core.setup(**kw)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.26-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 53, in run
        return _install.run(self)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 573, in run
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      File "/Users/username/build/pycrypto/setup.py", line 247, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
      File "/Users/username/build/pycrypto/setup.py", line 274, in run
        raise RuntimeError("autoconf error")
    RuntimeError: autoconf error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/username/build/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-u08kV1-record/install-record.txt:
    running install

running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/Crypto
copying lib/Crypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/Crypto
.........
copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/Crypto/Signature

running build_ext
running build_configure
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/username/build/pycrypto':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/username/build/pycrypto/setup.py", line 452, in <module>
    core.setup(**kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.26-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 53, in run
    return _install.run(self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 573, in run
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 127, in run
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
  File "/Users/username/build/pycrypto/setup.py", line 247, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
  File "/Users/username/build/pycrypto/setup.py", line 274, in run
    raise RuntimeError("autoconf error")
RuntimeError: autoconf error

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/username/build/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-u08kV1-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /Users/username/build/pycrypto
Storing complete log in /Users/username/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install XCode from the Apple App Store, and make sure you go into Preferences -> Downloads and install the Command line tools. You need a compiler.

Comment: Thanks so much jdi! I thought I had Xcode installed already, but that was on my old computer. All working great now.